# Django REST difference in views and viewsets

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a fairly simple REST api, but I still dont understand the difference between the type of views. Anything related to a model, I do through ModelViewSets and ModelSerializers. You can use the router, you have parameters in swagger docs, all good!

BUT, if I dont have a model (for example I have a function that accepts 2 parameters (var1 and var2) and the POST requests multiplies them, what is my best option? I prefer an option which involves a serializer as I am hoping to get parameters showing in the Swagger Documentation. I know I have the ViewSet option but that doesnt give me parameters in swagger. Is there any option that does give me those options?

EDIT:
I did find a semi solution. Please see the following code:

```
class Test1(generics.GenericAPIView):
    """
    Test
    """
    def get_queryset(self):
        print(123)
        return []

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return Test1Serializer
    
    def get(self, request):
        print('abc')
        return Response([1, 2, 3])
    
    def post(self, request):
        #multiply var1 and var2 here and return the result
```

In this example I am using the get_queryset method, but I wont use it (so it acts as a dummy). Can I just make that function return some empty array? What does happen then? Any better solutions? I feel like im abusing the use of GenericAPIView here. Isnt there a better solution using a normal ViewSet?

EDIT2: I updated the above code a bit. It now looks like this:

```
class Test1(generics.GenericAPIView):
    """
    Test
    """
    serializer_class = Test1Serializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        print('Running get_queryset')
        return [1, 2, 3, 4]
    
    def get(self, request):
        data = self.get_queryset()
        print('Queryset data', data)
        return Response(data)
    
    def post(self, request):
        return Response([1, 2, 3])
```

I am not using get_queryset as a dummy, but in there I can do the GET-request code. Doesnt this code run if I POST a request? Am I doing this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you are using django rest_framework. So if you have a function that takes two arguments and you want to post that request. You can simply use a functional based view for your post request with an @api_view decorater for you to be able to use Response. So you can try something like this:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
@api_view(['POST'])
def my_post_function(request, var1, var2):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        multi_result = var1*var2
        '''
        Do your post staff
        '''
        return Response({{"message": "Data posted", "data": request.data}})
```

To read more about functional based views you can checkout the documentation https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know about function based views. But that doesnt answer my question. They dont show up in the swagger docs, and I like the classes as they group different functions together

Comment: my apologies i had misunderstood the question